# Do the symmetric matrices form a Lie algebra with the same operation? What about the skew-symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

this is a question from In V.I.Arnold's book about ordinary differential equations. the Q:
Do the symmetric matrices form a Lie algebra with the same operation? What about the skew-symmetric matrices?
.The question came after the definition:A vector space with a binary operation possessing properties 1, 2 , and 3 is called a Lie algebra. Thus vector fields with the operation of commutation form a Lie algebra. This operation is just as fundamental for all of mathematics as addition and multiplica tion.

Comment: What operation?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the usual Lie algebra operations on $M_n(\Bbb R)$, if $A$ and $B$ are symmetric:

$A^T = A, \tag 1$

$B^T = B, \tag 2$

we have

$[A, B]^T = (AB - BA)^T = (AB)^T - (BA)^T$
$= B^TA^T - A^TB^T = BA - AB = [B, A] = -[A, B], \tag 3$

so $[A, B]$ is *skew-symmetric* and thus the symmetric matrices do ***not*** form a Lie algebra.

On the other had, with $A$ and $B$ skew,

$A^T = -A, \tag 4$

$B^T = -B, \tag 5$

$[A, B]^T = (AB - BA)^T = (AB)^T - (BA)^T$
$= B^TA^T - A^TB^T = (-B)(-A) - (-A)(-B)$
$= BA - AB = -[A, B], \tag 6$

which shows that $[A, B]$ is skew-symmetric, and thus that the skew-symmetric matrices do indeed form a Lie algebra.

The reader may easily extend this argument to showing that the skew-Hermitian matrices in $M_n(\Bbb C)$ form a Lie algebra, but that the Hermitian matrices do not.

Comment: When showing that the skew-symmetric matrices form a lie algebra don't we have to check also that [A,A]=0, and that the Jaccobi identity is satisfied? @Robert Lewis

Comment: Those were assumed for the operation of Lie bracket. And then [A, A]=0 was just checked as it is equivalent to the antisymmetry of the bracket to  see if it was met by symmetric or antisymmetric matrices.