# Understanding the lie algebra of the antisymmetric matrices

Tags: matrices, lie-algebras

I want to show that the set of antisymmetric matrices forms a lie algebra with respect to the bracket.

My definition of lie algebra is as follows:

Lie algebra over a field $F$ is an algebra (with an operation denoted by [ ] ) which satisfy:

1. $[x,x]=0$.
2. Jacobi identity:
   $[x,[y,z]]+[z,[x,y]]+[y,[z,x]]=0$.

I see (in the site in another question regarding this) that we have to show that

$[A,B]^T=-[A,B]$.

Why this is required?
Do not we have to check the two conditions mentioned above, so in this case how the bracket is defined?

Thanks

Comment: @CarloK.  the first requirement is closure, that the bracket of two skew symmetric matrices is once again skew symmetric.  I think the OP should be encouraged to calculate the 2 by 2 and 3 by 3 cases, matrices with letters as the nonzero elements

Comment: Ok, now more careful. You need to calculate closure as mentioned by @WillJagy and you need to check bi-linearity.

Comment: Sorry but i did not understand what was the discussion above about @Carlo K. Can you please clarify..

Comment: I was just super careless. You need the condition because a Lie algebra needs a well-defined operation $[-,-] \colon \mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g} $. The Lie bracket has to map pairs of objects in $\mathfrak{g}$ again to $\mathfrak{g}$. As said by @WillJagy you have to show that $[A,B]$, for skew symmetric matrices $A$, $B$, is again skew symmetric. Also you need to verify that $[-,-]$ is bi-linear, additionally to 1. and 2.

Comment: Thanks @Carlo K. So just to show the  same two conditions I menshined without any change (transpose etc,), right? .In addition to the condition you said and the bilinearity of the set of antisymmetric marices with respect to the bracket.

Comment: You show the conditions 1. and 2. as well as linearity: $[A, kB + k'B'] = k[A,B] + k' [A,B']$ and $[kA + k'A', B] = k[A,B] + k'[A',B]$ for all $k,k' \in F$ and $A$, $B$ skew symmetric matrices. Also you need to show $[A,B]^T = -[A,B]$ for closure.

Comment: Bestmat, please get some paper, write down  $$
G =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0&p&-q \\
-p&0&r \\
q&-r&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and 
$$
H =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0&x&-y \\
-x&0&z \\
y&-z&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and calculate, by hand, $GH,$   then $ HG.$  These have some interesting patterns in common. Finally, carefully  write $GH - HG $

Comment: Strongly agree with @WillJagy that the first thing to do here is to get your hands dirty and do the actual computations with $2\times 2$ and $3\times 3$-matrices. If you think you can skip that, you should skip doing mathematics altogether. -- That being said, once you have shown closure, i.e. that $[A,B]$ is skew-symmetric for $A,B$ skew-symmetric, you can forget about skew-symmetric matrices and should just show that $[A,B] := AB-BA$ satisfies $F$-bilinearity and your two conditions (anticommutativity and Jacobi) for any matrices (or indeed any elements of an associative $F$-algebra) $A, B$.

Comment: And related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3843148/96384

Answer (score 1):

Here's an overkill proof but probably goes a long way if you know about Lie Groups.

If $G$ is a Lie group then its tangent space at identity is a Lie algebra. Indeed it is isomorphic as Lie algebras to the Lie Algebra of left invariant vector fields on $G$.

Now consider the Lie group $O_n(\mathbb R)$. Its tangent space at identity is exactly the skew symmetric matrices. Hence it's a Lie algebra.

To see why the tangent space is that, here's an easy method.

Consider the curve $\gamma (t)$ passing through the identity matrix at $t=0$. By definition of orthogonal matrix we have $\gamma (t). \gamma (t) ^T - I = 0$. Differentiating both sides and putting $t=0$ gives us $\gamma(0) + \gamma(0) ^T = 0$. Which is exactly the definition of skew symmetric matrices.